# Task in a loop starts with wrong (last) index as parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm having issues with figuring out the Task class, I'm trying to have a process from the Process class run x amount of times. I attempted to accomplish this using the Background worker but when I run the process, it waits for the first one to complete before beginning the second one.

Here's what I'm trying to do now:

```
   ps = new Push(this)
   for (int counter = 1; counter <= maxgroup; counter++){              
         t = Task.Run(() => { ps.runCommand(strBatchPath, counter, username, password, password.getString()); });               
        }
```

For my "Push" class here's the method I'm calling,

```
    public void runCommand(string batchfile, int groupnumber, string username, SecureString securePassword, string password)
    {
        formControl.setTextbox(groupnumber.ToString());
        string number = groupnumber.ToString();
        string tmp = "/c c:\\psexec.exe -c @c:\\Computers\\group" + number + ".txt -u MYDOMAINNAME\\" + username + " -p " + password + " -h " + @batchfile;


        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        formControl.setTextbox(tmp);
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = tmp;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;                  
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        //* Read the output (or the error)
        // string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.OutputDataReceived += process_DataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorReceived;


        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();


    }
```

My issue is when I'm looping (from 1 to 2 lets say) 
My first iteration Counter = 1
when I pass counter to

```
      ps.runCommand();
```

counter starts at 3
so in the runCommand function, 
it's calling group3.txt twice, instead of group1.txt, group2.txt

I changed it and am now using async/await

```
         ps = new Push(this);
            for (int counter = 1; counter <= maxgroup; counter++)
            {

                await Task.Run(() =>  ps.runCommand(strBatchPath, counter, username, password, password.getString()) ); 
    }
```

This is working actually.. kind of, It's just going one at a time. So after the first task finishes, it starts the second one. How can I make it so that it runs BOTH tasks at the same time? Thank you for any assistance!!

Comment: Do you know which version of C# you are using here?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios 2015, so i believe it's C#6.0